# Removing rows which contains some strings

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to remove all the rows which contains at least one of these strings:

```
to_remove=['january','jan','feb','mar','apr','may','th','adf','ng','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
```

I have tried as follows

```
text = text[~ text.T.str.contains('|'.join(to_remove))]
```

but this remove everything because I think they remove also words which contains `a` or `b` and not `a` or `b` as strings.

So if I have:

```
T

a
story
wonderful
January
b
...
```

I would like to have

```
T

story
wonderful
January
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Book':['This','is','a','book','about','b','wonderful','things']})
to_remove = ['a','b']

print(df)
df['Book'] = df.Book.apply(lambda x: x if x not in to_remove else np.nan)
df = df.dropna()
print(df)
```

The dataframe before removing the items:

```
        Book
0       This
1         is
2          a
3       book
4      about
5          b
6  wonderful
7     things
```

The dataframe after you have removed the items:

```
        Book
0       This
1         is
3       book
4      about
6  wonderful
7     things
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
to_remove = ['a', 'b']
list_ = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
edited_list = [row for row in list_ if row not in to_remove]
```

Output:

```py
> ['c', 'd']
```

Comment: my list should be a pandas column. Is it the same?

Comment: @Math anyway you can turn column into list using `.tolist()`